# Twitch Bot in Java using 25%+ CPU for select users

Tags: java, cpu-usage

I am developing a Twitch Bot that is built in C# for the GUI and Java for the logic. I have about 100+ users so far but I have heard complaints from 5 users that the Java process uses 25-30%+ CPU usage. Whereas for me and 95% of the users it never reaches above 5% even when it is being tested very hard. It's not operating system because some of the users use Windows 7, 8.1, and 10. Does anyone have an idea on why there would be such a difference for these select users? I have tried looking into many different aspects but cannot find the problem.

Comment: Sounds like an infinite loop somewhere, 25% CPU use on a quad core would be one thread stuck in a loop.

Comment: @john16384 Or busy-waiting instead of blocking.